# Why doesn't messaging app convert smiley shortcut codes to smileys?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, sms, messaging

Why does messaging app Windows 10 Mobile doesn't automatically convert smiley shortcut codes to smileys? Because it is very irritating for me when I receive messages with lots of smileys and I don't understand what do they mean. Then I have to check a reference for these shortcut codes. Is there any solution to this problem?

[image: Sample SMS with unconverted smiley shortcut codes]